# How can I improve django mysql copy performance?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, mysql-python

I have a django app that has a model (`Person`) defined and I also have some DB (in there is a table `Appointment`) that do not have any models defined (not meant to be connected to the django app).

I need to move some data from `Appointment` table over to the `Person` such that all information the People table needs to mirror the Appointment table. It is this way because there are multiple independent DBs like Appointment that needs to be copied to the Person table (so I do not want to make any architectural changes to how this is setup).

[image: img]

Here is what I do now:

```
res = sourcedb.fetchall() # from Appointment Table
for myrecord in res:
    try:
        existingrecord = Person.objects.filter(vendorid = myrecord[12], office = myoffice)[0]
    except:
        existingrecord = Person(vendorid = myrecord[12], office = myoffice)

    existingrecord.firstname    = myrecord[0]
    existingrecord.midname      = myrecord[1]
    existingrecord.lastname     = myrecord[2]
    existingrecord.address1     = myrecord[3]
    existingrecord.address2     = myrecord[4]
    existingrecord.save()
```

The problem is that this is way too slow (takes about 8 minutes for 20K records). What can I do to speed this up?

I have considered the following approach:

**1. [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):** Cannot use this because I have to update sometimes.

**2. delete all and then bulk_create** There is dependency on the Person model to other things, so I cannot delete records in Person model.

**3. INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:** cannot do this because the Person table's PK is different from the Appointment table PK (primary key). The Appointment PK is copied into Person table. If there was a way to check on two duplicate keys, this approach would work I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas:

- **EDIT**: See Trewq's comment to this and create Indexes on your tables first of all…
- Wrap it all in a transaction using `with transaction.atomic():`, as by default Django will create a new transaction per `save()` call which can become very expensive. With 20K records, one giant transaction might also be a problem, so you might have to write some code to split your transactions into multiple batches. Try it out and measure!
- If RAM is not an issue (should not be one with 20k records), fetch all data first from the appointment table and then fetch all existing Person objects using a single `SELECT` query instead of one per record
- Use `bulk_create` even if some of them are updates. This will still issue `UPDATE` queries for your updates, but will reduce all your `INSERT` queries to just one/a few, which still is an improvement. You can distinguish inserts and updates by the fact that inserts wont have a primary key set before calling `save()` and save the inserts into a Python list for a later `bulk_create` instead of saving them directly
- As a last resort: Write raw SQL to make use of MySQLs `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax. You don't need the same primary key for this, a `UNIQUE` key would suffice. Keys can span multiple columns, see Django's `Meta.unique_together` model option.

Comment: The problem was simply that I needed to create an index - I was then able to run the query in 76 seconds, and when I used the atomic(), I was able to get this in 56 seconds.

Comment: Well, sometimes it is easier than one thinks…